# Presenting HTTP service securely with HTTPS

Tags: networking, web-server, webcam, security

I've successfully configured a Motion webcam server for monitoring my puppy as he destroys the kitchen:  The video is presented within an HTML page with allows for basic HTTP authentication, but is presented only with an **un**secure HTTP (http://192.168.1.20:8081) connection.

As I would ultimately like to present this stream externally (I'm familiar with port forwarding), I was wondering how I would go about presenting this with HTTP**S** to prevent eavesdropping and ensure the password information sent is invisible.

I know it would be possible to somehow proxy this on the Pi, but I do not know the terminology to search for or where to begin looking!

The desired end state would be to connect to http**s**://myFreeDomain.net/, provide credentials and then view the webpage presented internally as http://192.168.1.20:8081.

The Motion service can present the webpage as http:// localhost if needed.

Thanks in advance for any advice or examples you can provide, or any additional help,

James

Comment: *"I know it would be possible to somehow proxy this on the Pi, but I do not know the terminology to search for or where to begin looking!"* -> In fact you do.  You want arrange a (forward) proxy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server Take "server" to refer to a piece of software and not "discrete machine".

Comment: Thanks, @goldilocks - Thanks for the pointer to "forward proxying", I'll see how I get on now I know I'm looking in the right place!

Comment: As C Malasadas pointed out, you'll need an SSL certificate. They don't have to cost money. [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a free, trusted SSL provider that I use on my own projects.

Comment: Also, you can create your own CA (certificate authority), use that to sign the server certificate, and install the CA cert into a web browser and it will trust your server.  Doesn't cost anything, doesn't require any one else, and is only 5 minutes more complicated than creating a self-signed cert.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks - I'll have a look at creating my own CA in the future, but will wimp out now as my geek stamina is waning. Solution posted.

Comment: TBH: Unless you have a stubborn device somewhere with stubborn software that refuses to allow you to visit "untrusted" sites, and/or you are worried you are being stalked by someone capable of a man-in-the-middle attack, it is probably more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

Right, I got there in the end!

Using Apache 2.2.22

## SSL Proxy Configuration

Install Apache2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Enable Apache2 Modules for Proxying & SSL

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Create directory and SSL Cert

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl/

sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/puppycam.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/puppycam.crt
```

Configured as follows:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:UK
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Berkshire
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Tilehurst
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:mysite
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:puppycam.mysite.com
Email Address []:administrator@mysite.com
```

Create VirtualHost File for service:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-SecureWebcam.conf
```

Contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


ProxyRequests Off
SSLProxyEngine On

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>


ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.20:8081/
#ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.20:8081/

<Location /proxy/>
  ProxyPassReverse /
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/puppycam.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/puppycam.key





                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown



</VirtualHost>
```

Enable Site

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-SecureWebcam.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-SecureWebcam.conf
```

Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Test access to webcam from https://192.168.1.22 (internal address of Apache server)

## Install & Configure Dynamic DNS (for Google Domains)

Accept all defaults - we wil change later

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient
```

Edit the ddclient config

```
sudo vim /etc/ddclient.conf
```

Contents:

```
ssl=yes
protocol=googledomains
use=web
server=domains.google.com
login=thisisasecret
password='thisisalsoasecret'
puppycam.mysite.com
```

## Security Configuration

Create a directory for the password file

```
sudo mkdir /etc/htpasswd/
```

Add a user to the password file

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd james
```

Edit the VirtualHost configuration to add authentication:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-SecureWebcam.conf
```

Modify the `<Proxy *>` section as follows:

```
...
<Proxy *>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
...
```

Enable the appropriate authentication modules:

```
sudo a2enmod authn_file
sudo a2enmod auth_basic
```

Restart Apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

## Mop Up Actions

1. Perform network capture to be sure allk traffic is secure (no plain
   text password)
2. Configure Port Forwarding on router
3. Test remote access